# Combine multiple datasets in a more compact way

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

Whenever I have several datasets that I want to load and combine into a single dataset, so that I can analyse all of them at the same time, I do something like

```
for(i in 1:length(dataset_paths))
{
  data_path <- list.files(path = paste0(here(dataset_paths[i]), "results/analysis/"), pattern = ".*\\.degradation_dynamics\\.csv", full.names = TRUE)
  t_dt <- fread(data_path)
  if(i == 1)
  {
    dt <- t_dt
  }
  dt <- rbind(dt, t_dt)
}
rm(t_dt)
dt %>% setkey(frame)
```

This code is quite *ugly*.

Is there a way to make this code more smaller & more understandable?

For instance by

- Getting rid of the *if* condition inside the loop
- Getting rid of the `1:length(dataset_paths)` expression
- Getting rid of defining a temporary variable `t_dt`
  ?

Comment: `my_df <- vroom::vroom(data_path)` using the [vroom package](https://vroom.r-lib.org/#reading-multiple-files).

Comment: Iteratively adding rows to a frame using `rbind(old, newrow)` works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). For each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like `foreach` for this purpose:

```
require(data.table)
require(foreach)

dt <- foreach( path = dataset_paths, .combine='rbind' ) %do% {
  
  dt_t <- fread(path)
  
}

setkey(dt,frame)
```

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the following code is not tested, but using `lapply` you do something like:

```
dt <- lapply(dataset_paths, function(x) {
  data_path <- list.files(path = here(x, "results", "analysis"), pattern = ".*\\.degradation_dynamics\\.csv", full.names = TRUE)
  fread(data_path)
})
dt <- do.call(rbind, dt)
dt %>% setkey(frame)
```

Comment: Since this is assuming `data.table`, any reason you chose against `rbindlist`?

Comment: This can be sped up a bit by doing a single call to `list.files`: `list_of_dat <- lapply(list.files(dataset_paths, pattern="..", full.names=TRUE), fread)`, then `rbindlist(list_of_dat)`.

Comment: @r2evans. Thx for your comments and suggestions. Have to confess that - except for some basics - I'm not familiar with `data.table`.

Comment: This is how I learned `data.table` (not that I consider myself perfectly fluent in it), attempting questions on SO. FYI, `rbindlist(..)` typically out-performs `do.call(rbind, ..)` in speed, and adds arguments to allow additional or out-of-order columns, via `fill=TRUE, use.names=TRUE` (respectively). There are no times I've found where `do.call(rbind, ..)` was better in any form. (Not yet at least :-).